# android layout multiple tag

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm not sure how to go about googling this problem. How do I use multiple libraries in a single attribute?

E.g.

```
<com.hb.views.PinnedSectionListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lvInspection"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="false" />
```

Now I want to include one more tag to have the swipe effect:

```
com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuListView
```

Thank you.

Comment: This is impossible. The tag indicate this is a class instance of specific type. You cannot have one instance to be of type of two classes.

Comment: Sad... Is there any other ways to go about it?

Comment: you concept is wrong, I suppose. Never found such uses in Android.

Comment: That's because I need the header to be pinned and also allow rows to be swiped...